# Did any philosophers defend Slave Morality?

Tags: ethics, society

I think slave morality creates a peaceful society and Master morality would be negative for most people. To restrain ambition and desire is one of the reasons mankind have survived so long.

But slave morality in itself seems to be intended as an insult. Did any philosophers outright say slave morality is good for society?

EDIT: With slave morality I mean that it is better to have meaning granted by a master, not create your own. Slave morality is like a herd of sheep that look at an eagle, that takes whatever it wants, and says "look at that terrible creature!". It is an ideology based on resentment of strength and those who are too successful are cut down. It's sort of like the beliefs of a weak community working together to prevent strong master-morality people to appear, or at least condemn their superiority.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master%E2%80%93slave_morality

Comment: I assume that terminology comes from somewhere. You have to say where it comes from and what it means if you want this question to make any sense.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

I mean browsing the Wiki articles in English and German Nietzsche himself already mentions several groups in favor of what HE calls slave morality. Judaism, Christianity, Jesuits, the free press, the democratic movement "(is) the political manifestation of slave morality because of its obsession with freedom and equality". And so on.

The thing is they are likely not going to think of it as "slave morality". That is Nietzsches opinion of them. But if you're talking about "freedom (and equality)" you are likely not perceiving that as slavery. It's Nietzsche for whom those ideas are mere self-deception of the slaves who pretend their vices to be virtues, in order to "rebel" against their oppression without bridging over to master morality. Which he apparently thinks is not very rebellious and something to give up.

I'm not an expert on Nietzsche so if someone is more knowledgeable feel free to correct me, but from what I understand Nietzsche characterizes "Master Morality" as the ability to CREATE morality. "Power" in that sense is not primarily domination, but self-actualization. It's the ability to "pick your own goal". He uses the term "vornehm" which is apparently translated with "noble" and while it also has that connotation in German, the literal meaning of "vornehmen" is "to intent (to do something)", "to make a plan". So the "master" is not necessarily the owner of a slave, but someone who is acting, who has agency over themselves and thus his morality is simply divided into "things that further my goal" (vornehm/noble) and "things that don't" (verächtlich/contemptible). He basically distinguishes less between "good and evil" but more between "success and failure". So it's "good" that comes first, and "bad" that is just a consequence of "not being good".

While in terms of the slave morality it's the other way around. As the slave is deprived of the ability to make their own moral, either by a lack of courage or by the oppression of a master, they essentially have two options, either to adopt a master morality without the ability to act upon it and thus be "immoral" or the development of a slave morality that basically consists of rejecting the master morality and to cherish things which reduce the pain of servitude. So the "evil" comes first and "good" is the absence of evil.

Where the master morality creates moral value based on sentiment, the slave morality rejects such values based on resent(i)ment. Master morality is initial action, slave morality is reaction. And where Nietzsche seems to place no limits on the master morality and sees it as only restraint by the master's volition. He apparently thinks that the slave morality goes too far in the sense that the rejection of "the master", to him means the rejection of self-actualization, the rejection of desire, the rejection of agency, the rejection of oneself.

Usefulness to him is not a value in itself, but a tool that serves a purpose. And by upholding this "usefulness" the slave upholds his own slavery. For him it's something like being forced to work the fields, while someone else is feasting and as a result you stop them from feasting and make them work the fields as well. Meaning you haven't actually ended your slavery, you haven't even gotten rid of the master's morality as you're still serving it, you've just gotten rid of any sense of the master's morality as you're still serving it, but they are no longer benefiting from it. So in a sense you've declared your slavery a virtue in itself, which is likely seen as an ultimate act of submission, because the consequence is that you're arguing that "slavery is your choice" and not just the result of oppression.

Now the question is "are these anarchistic ideals of 'no god, no state, no slave, no master'" expressions of slave morality and of self-enslavement, which rejects once and for all rejects one's own agency and makes oneself the cog in a machine of a master or even a masterless machine, subject to the whims of nature? Or are they the genuine self-expression of the those people.

Like what if you are of the genuine impression that the absence of a tyrant and a society of equals serves the purpose of self-actualization MORE than being the tyrant. Like being a tyrant and having other people with a master morality seeking not to accommodate themselves with my rule but to overthrow me and be the tyrant results in a violent free-for-all, where my "power" to self-actualize is mostly guaranteed by my power to dominate others, meaning I'd spend most of my time wasting my power to preserve my power. Which in terms of "using my power to do what I want to do", is actively detrimental to my own goal. It's **immoral**, not even because I'd be a douche, but because it'd fail to do what I actually desire to do. So I'd violate my own (master) morality. I'd be a powerless slave of the necessity to dominate.

So while Nietzsche probably sees them as the ultimate act of submission and might be right in some instances and wrong in others, usually these movements themselves would see their exact action as an action as a demand for agency. So it's unlikely that they would call it "slave morality" as this contradicts their own impression. The only place where that might work is probably in terms of religion where the mission statement is often surprisingly close to what Nietzsche describes where the submission to a god is the praised and where "slavery as a choice" is quite literally what idk monks/nuns are, but even they would probably not see it as some internalized oppression but as an act of voluntary self-expression. He might disagree, but he's not the moral arbiter of their morality, is he?

I fear I've made quite some assertions on what I think Nietzsche thinks, so again if people know more about it, feel free to correct the parts that need citations or whatnot.

Comment: Master morality is an initial point for the oneself action - "freedom for (good)", slave morality is guide to the reaction - "freedom from (evil)".

Comment: And good is not that word because Jenseits von Gut und Böse

Comment: @άνθρωπος sounds like a simplification with regards to that being the entire morality, but I can certainly see that in that description (freedom to and freedom from). And yes it's beyond good and evil but he still uses "gut" und "schlecht" for the master morality.

Comment: is vornehm same as  Übermench?

Comment: @άνθρωπος Reading further "vornehm" might also refer to "taking first" or "taking (nehmen) before (vor) others", in the sense of a privileged position, so nobility might actually fit. Either way he's using it as a positively connotated synonym for "good" in terms of master morality. One interpretation of Nietzsche's work is apparently as a rejection of universal morality and uniformity which he contrasts with hyperindividualism Which is ambivalent as it in on the one hand can be read as radical endorsement of life and creativity to fill the void left by the rejection of morality ...

Comment: While on the other hand it can be quite easily read as an endorsement of some "Darwinism", "prosperity gospel", "eugenics" aso. Where through constant struggle, "the best" is crystallize out. Which results in his Übermensch (super human) to be somewhere between a obsessed loner and a genocidal tyrant. So not actually defining Übermensch is conjectured to be deliberate as any definition would be like the term human itself, be an attempt to uniform a group, rather than affirm individuality. So technically vornehm would be a characteristic of the master morality which breeds the "Übermensch".

Comment: I have doubts about your assumption that vornehm morality is the Übermensch cradle, in spite of it opposition to slave morality(nehmen). Because minority slave morality ofc is moral of nehmen, but major cause of Slave morality is system of cooperation between master and it's slaves, through servants or ministers. Whole system have a view sovereign/sir-minister-slave or power-agent-subject. If you reject subject from the system all system will not able to exist, that is a problem, that Nietzsche didn't solve, when he tried to realize his Ubermensh.

Comment: And second argument that in esse homo he said that Ubermensh is at opposition stance to good people(christians and nihilists doesn't matter), as Zaratustra est at opposition to any morality. That mean that Ubermensh is not ever master or belong to major Slave morality complex. The cause of Ubermensh is not ever in good motives or good beginnings, not vornish(?). Because both good and evil are belong to SM, Ubermensh cases are not begin for the good or from at evil intentions, but they can be a cause of both good and evil

Comment: o this from nearest question about joke "Despised by me are following and leading." Both followers and leaders are at Despised of (Ubermensh)xD. So, this is the mistake to interpret SM as something belong to UM or especially(!) think that master good morality can be preceding at something to Ubermensh. Because good is more worst then evil, evil is a clear and notable bad, good is an undetectable bad.

Comment: @άνθρωπος The German language is ambiguous in that regard. Good is both the one part of "good and evil" which characterize slave morality, but the master morality nonetheless creates edge cases of desirable and undesirable which Nietzsche calls "good and bad". Or "vornehm (noble) and verächtlich (contemptible)". Though that should not be confused with "good" and "noble" in the framework of "good and evil", they aren't universal or dogmatic but subjective and self-defined by the individual.

Comment: i understand that you try to say, but as ive got understand, words subjective and individual are definitely not that words that you can use to describe this problem, doesn't matter what semantic meaning you try to give them. Because subjective is a thing under force, that mean subjects are same as slaves, but force can be not only physical also moral(at the first moment) cause of slave is a subjective existence of the thing, slave is not being, slave is a thing. also the individual "single object or thing" that get meaning "a single human being". An here ass you see a man become a hu+man

Comment: Man is someone in Eng that not a slave and not a master, but human is someone inscribed in major SM in roles slaves or overseers.

Comment: In this domination doctrine, Subjects can't mind about moral or it causes , they can only react on good or evil, sensing, and if you look in nowadays this reactions are calls emotions. All this system subordinated by emotions and predefined chooses: likes, voting,  preferences, fashion, trends, PR, propaganda, information... Nothing about causal of something, only meaning. In language this calls semantic, where the word is a sing, not named cause. True is a sing on some evidence, no cause true. Nietzsche tried to invented something new, but found causes of "brave new world", that is now

Comment: @άνθρωπος You seem to operate with a different semantic meaning, I mean subject in the sense of the distinction between a subject (an acting agent) and an object (a thing). And individual in the sense of a particular thing, a single object or person. Like Nietzsche is criticizing uniform, universal, fit-all moralities because they don't fit those who don't fit in the template. And so he's arguing in favor of a individualism, in favor of breaking the mold. Which is ambiguous in terms of good and evil as it's both life affirming and destructive and cruel.

Comment: Subject is an action agent, only because an agent is under sir power, power conductor. Don't look at semantic, look at causes. In this cause both subjective agents and objects-wordless slaves are the lord's subjects. Lord is not an object and not a subject - he have Name, not an individuality or nominative, you d confused in semantic wordplay, don't look at semantic, it causeless, semantic have only sense meaning. You missed that major SM is "sir-minister-slave or power-agent-subject" - not master-slave - that is incomplete picture.

Comment: You go silent. You think that i try to confuse you? Or i have a mistake? Probably, but i find only that i have no mistake. "It is not my words" i find it in etymology dictionary and it is not conflict with logic, and more, it put all on their places. early 14c., "person under control or dominion of another," - etymonline.com .

Comment: In true that subjection have two levels. Sensitive reflexes level, and law-rules reflexes - this part you call consequence or objective reality. But thay are reflexes too, emotions are reflexes. So you got true subjective - inner world based on self sensitive, and smart subjective based on world of things and meanings, rules that was designed by another - God, unknown Lord, experts society ... Especially new laws tendencias based on non-authority of rules , but they have support of many other good people - experts of some clubs or societies. But you still say about subject under law power.

Comment: And here you make one more smart trick. You say, you may not follow the rule, but you got this then - so it is rule for rule cancelling. All system of object world founded on this principles, tricks, logic fallacies - you are free when you are playing in our game by our rules. You are free to win. Oh, stop stop, you have chance to win. NVM just continue playing, rules are fair trust it, if rules are not fair look point 1. We not need God to create fair laws, but thy may not to create self rule because, you are subject under rules.. and ect and same

Comment: @άνθρωπος Sorry being silent is nothing personal, I was just unable to respond and later forgot about it. Yes I am of that meaning of the word as well as the fact that "sub - ject" literally means "to throw under" and I usually don't like calling things an "etymological fallacy" especially when the etymology is still relevant. But in this case I think it kind of misses the point. The point was precisely that the subject has agency, so to redefine it as not having agency is a semantic argument not really a logical one, right?

Comment: @άνθρωπος Though yes I see your point, individual would be fitting but subjective in that meaning of submission is kind of antithetical to the concept that I tried to express.

Comment: in this view point - yes, freedom concept is fiction. Why? Because thou doest not need be free to art, but you need free from other "I" to act. Thou as out of free, beyond free part of mind was  cut in 19th century (this process was strat at 16th). So you have only you. You are never not alone from others. Others is objective reality, world of things, and subject - you - should to be under objective reality laws. So you got strange and inverted causal structure of mind, where subject is under will of many objects. This subject become to call hu+man. What is hu+?

Comment: Hu is reduction from humus, fertile part of the earth, that is good for to grow plants. Next a word is culture, culture is borrowed from plant cultivation, culture plant - good plant. As before wise men grew plants, nowaday they grew humans. That fun and looks like joke, but it so straight in logic). There are also fun other words, like homo sapience - homo=slave sapience first meaning is tasty, sensitive  = tasty slave, good slave, useful slave. Ofc you should to consider all of this as my joke. About symbolic. Statue of Liberty(Freedom) - we not need libertatem if we was "free".

Comment: And also the image of SoL is modern view on Gekata's statue. Gekata Luciferia, in Eng Liberty Enlightening the World. But classical Gekata the goddess of crossroads that leads in underworld, that why she needs torches. And ect. For me this facts in single case are senseless, but in complex i look not on the facts, but on logic. All logic is inverted to logic that was before. Where man was free man, not culture man, man under culture - human. That what your freedom is. And ofc it is connected to economics and politics realizings

Comment: i don't think that it can be called lying. But it is like bubbles, some areas when you have inverted logic, inverted to outside(or inner) bubbles. It is not about religion, or moral, it is just a method to separate Wheat from Chaff. It is the method to detection Contract.

Comment: « Si la société de consommation ne produit plus de mythe, c’est qu’elle est elle-même son propre mythe. À un Diable qui apportait l’Or et la Richesse (au prix de l’âme) s’est substituée l’Abondance pure et simple. Et au pacte avec le Diable le contrat d’Abondance. » La Société de consommation est un ouvrage Jean Baudrillard

Comment: the cause that every animal consider the normal that was imprinted while it born. And only "Man is able to born twice", 'first time in-from culture environment as social personality', 'second time - alone, as Person that have Name'. 'You' have a big problems with second born. Because all concepts that you ll express are based on inverted logic of Underworld.

Comment: @άνθρωπος Interesting but also kinda sketchy. Like do you have any sources for that? I mean Nietzsche didn't even use "human" but "Mensch" which is apparently derived from just "man" though used both to denote a male and a human. Needless to say he didn't like that either. Human apparently actually has similarity with humus, though I've no idea why. Are these creatures that live upon and from humus or compose to it? Was it a way to denote agrarian as those that ate from (stuff planted in) humus? To see it as humans being compared to humus is one interpretation but far from being the only one.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145919/discussion-between-haxor789-and-).

Answer (score -2):

All of your senses are grated by wise people, so don't worry, all your World based on Slave morality. When you see something, you are asking: what that mean? And that mean, that you can not to sense about something by self, without receiving outside notification about the sense. Outer instruction from a book, a movie, web, chat or from another communication.

So i don't understand what are you worry about? Are you a slave, that donno that he a slave, but worried that he may not a slave?